# I can not set a http proxy in Blender

Tags: network

I am using Blender behind a firewall with a proxy.
When anything , e.g. an addon needs to connect to the internet, this fails.
Is there a way to set a http/https proxy in blender ?
(assuming using Blender on Win10)

Comment: Sorry just a comment, i got the same problem with Blenderkit (i paid with 2.79) and now it isn

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you need to add `http_proxy` (and `https_proxy`, maybe?) to your environment variables. You can do this with the built-in (terrible) windows tool for this (a duckduckgo search will find [lots of pages](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=add%20environment%20variable%20windows%2010&atb=v249-1&ia=web) showing you how) or the (much more useable) [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download).

The variable you add is `http_proxy` and the value will be something like `http://mycompanyproxyserver:3128` where `3128` is the port number. I did the same for `https_proxy`, I'm not sure if this is necessary or not.

Once you've added the variable you need to refresh your shell— the easiest way is to log out / in, or restart.